# [Solved]MySQL index work in one table and not work in another table when using IN

Tags: mysql, index

I was asked if the index is working or not when we use `IN` keyword in `MySQL` like below:

```
 //suppose col has index and the value is almost unique
 SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col IN('xxx','yyy','zzz');
```

In order to get the accurate result, I do the test myself,I created two tables,and index works on one table but not work on another table,I do not know why.Hope someone helps me understand it.Thanks in advance.

The first table is called `system_users` :

```
CREATE TABLE system_users(
  id INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME CHAR(15),
  gender CHAR(1),
  age INT(2),
  department CHAR(1),
  email VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE INDEX name_index ON system_users(NAME);

INSERT  INTO system_users(id,NAME,gender,age,department,email) 
  VALUES 
(1,'euser_izpwhzzcz','1',37,'1','yvmk0oqm0lf@mail.com'),
(2,'muser_czepyfklv','1',20,'1','a9wq08gcllk@mail.com'),
(3,'tuser_mwrluajek','0',20,'1','o8jqqebi0bt@mail.com'),
(4,'duser_jzgpheafx','0',22,'2','hegehgsbfmg@mail.com'),
(5,'auser_iacjkekhg','0',36,'2','46drnrja29i@mail.com'),
(6,'euser_eikhwvwsi','1',31,'2','56amq6nayde@mail.com'),
(7,'muser_lblozikah','1',29,'3','qlbtvpzgrej@mail.com'),
(8,'cuser_xhsuuzzur','0',35,'3','klrr6kurylg@mail.com'),
(9,'vuser_iwmklbyzp','0',22,'3','ngdrlguhzrp@mail.com'),
(10,'buser_yfnffsfoc','0',37,'4','o1jvffj4ahu@mail.com');
```

Now,when I use `EXPLAIN` to analysis below query sql,I found the index works

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM system_users WHERE NAME IN('euser_eikhwvwsi','buser_yfnffsfoc');
```

**As we see the value of `type` is `range`,in this scenario index seems works when use `IN`**
[image: Index work when use IN]

---

The second table is called `test`:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c1 VARCHAR(10),
  c2 VARCHAR(10),
  c3 VARCHAR(10),
  c4 VARCHAR(10),
  c5 VARCHAR(10)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE INDEX c_index ON test(c1);

INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('b1','b2','b3','b4','b5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('c1','c2','c3','c4','c5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('d1','d2','d3','d4','d5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('e1','e2','e3','e4','e5');

INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('a1','b1','c1','d1','e1');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('b1','a2','b2','b4','b5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('c1','a3','c3','d4','c5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('d1','a4','d3','d4','d5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('e1','a5','b5','e4','e5');
```

Now when I use `EXPLAIN` to analysis below sql,**the index seem not work since the `value` of type is `all`**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE c1 IN('a1','b1');
```

[image: Index not work when use IN]

**Both of the two tables has ordinary column and datas,but when use `IN`,why the `type` of one is `range` while the other is `all`?**

PS:The version of `MySQL` in my side is **`5.0.67`**,I have run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for both table and still get the same result.

Below are the result when execute `ANALYZE TABLE`

[image]

Note:**I have found it has something to do with the data amount in my version,if I insert hundreds of data,then the explain result are expected**

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you should and will get index utilized in your explain plan.  I am not sure why you are getting different plans, but I have got the same by executing your code as it is.

First plan[image]

And the second plan:
[image]

There may some fragmentation/table stats issue.  would you execute OPTIMIZE TABLE or ANALYZE TABLE on your tables to see the correct plan?

Comment: I tried but got the same result and my database version is `5.0.67`

Comment: @Rick James  I wonder if this is something version related?

Comment: I did not see Rick James,why do you @ him?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way to ask him to come in here.  However, he, indeed, would have much more clarity on this version related things.  May be you can tag/ask him on this.

Comment: @lucumt - Well, @'ing me did not work because he left a space in my username.  But I am here anywhere.

Comment: This Answer is apparently using a newer version than the OP.  My Answer explains why the index may or may not be used in the given tests, and why it could vary with version, data size, etc, etc.  I may be one of the few forum trolls with experience dating back to 5.0.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  This explains

Answer (score 0):

Do not panic if `EXPLAIN` seems to be ignoring an obviously good index.  The Optimizer may have a good reason.

When the Optimizer sees that only a "small percentage" of the index will be needed, it uses the index.  If a "large percentage" is needed, the Optimizer will scan the data instead of bouncing back and forth between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.  This 'bouncing' is likely to be more costly than the seemingly wasteful full table scan.  The Optimizer makes an educated guess as to which is better, but may not guess right, especially when near the cutoff.

The cutoff is somewhere around 20%, but it depends on many things, seemingly even the phase of the moon.

In your tiny examples, the first wanted 3 rows out of 10 (30%).  The second needs 4/10 (40%).  Apparently, the first was deemed "small" and the second, "large".

If you add more items to the first IN, it may switch to a table scan.  If you add more rows (without 'a1' or 'b1), it may switch to using the index.  Etc.

"Range" -- Normally, "range" means to start with one value and scan linearly until hitting another value.  A "range" scan (of either the index or the data) is likely to happen for `BETWEEN`, `<`, etc.  But, be aware that `EXPLAIN` is less than perfect in many of its areas.  I *think* that the use of "range" for `IN` really means to probe the BTree for each item.  The "Rows" column is an *estimate*; your test cases are so small that "2" and "4" do not provide any useful information.

"Using index" -- Read about "covering" indexes.

"Using index condition" (new in 5.6) -- This is something different.  It refers to where other conditions (other than those looked up in the index) are handled:  Either in the engine-independent "Handler", or inside InnoDB (faster).

As for why the previous Answer shows the index being used -- the phase of the moon.  Seriously, it is probably statistics or maybe changes in the Optimizer.

There have been Optimizer changes, but what I say above is *effectively* unchanged anywhere in the version range of 4.0 to 8.0.  (You should really upgrade from 5.0 for many other reasons.)